# Trigger is not activating in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to program a maze in Unity where you have to pick up a key in order to open door somewhere else. I put colliders on both the key and the door and have set the script to do different things when the player collides with them. here's the script. The problem is that the key allows the player to pass through it, but it doesn't mark it as the player has collected the key nor does it destroy the key either. Both the door and key have "is Trigger" checked.

```
public class DetectCollide : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static string hasKey = "n";


    void Start()
    {

    }


    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {

        if(other.name == "Main Camera")
         {
             if(gameObject.name == "Key")
             {
                 
                 hasKey = "y";
                 Destroy(gameObject);
             }
             if((gameObject.name == "ArchDoor") && (hasKey == "y"))
             {
                 Destroy(gameObject);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the key and the player must contain a `Collider` component: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

> Both GameObjects must contain a Collider component. One must have Collider.isTrigger enabled, and contain a Rigidbody. If both GameObjects have Collider.isTrigger enabled, no collision happens. The same applies when both GameObjects do not have a Rigidbody component.

Are all the prerequisites in place?

Please also change the code and see if it enters at all in the function

```
    private void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log("OtherName: " + other.name + "gameObject: " + gameObject.name);
        if(other.name == "Main Camera")
         {
             if(gameObject.name == "Key")
             {
                 
                 hasKey = "y";
                 Destroy(gameObject);
             }
             if((gameObject.name == "ArchDoor") && (hasKey == "y"))
             {
                 Destroy(gameObject);
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Yes and it still didn't trigger

Comment: Can you share them both? Because this one does not contain a `Rigidbody` and we might spot something with the other one.

Comment: It appears to not even enter the function seeing as nothing happened after the change

Comment: Are you sure that your Main Camera code contains both a Collider and a Rigidbody?

Comment: Are you using a `RigidBody` or a `RigidBody2D` ? You should use `OnTriggerEnter2D` method and Collider2D If you are using a `RigidBody2D`. And one of them should have `IsTrigger` set to True.

Answer (score 0):

> It appears to not even enter the function seeing as nothing happened
> after the change

The problem lies withing your function name, Unitys custom functions (eg. `Update`, `Start` and [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)) are all case sensitive and will not be called if they don't have the exact same name.

**Example:**

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {}
```

Instead of `onTriggerEnter()`, because you need to make sure that the O on [`OnTriggerEnter()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) is higher case like it should be. Or your function won't be called and therefore not trigger your collision like you wanted.